# Adding an event listener to a dynamically created div, and passing this to it

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've found similar questions about passing variables, but none about passing this.

I'm trying to create a div based on input to a form, then attach an event listener calling an event that requires this to be passed to it. I've gotten to the point where it creates the div, and adds the content based on the entered data. So now I'm trying to add the onClick event using .addEventListener, but it appears you can't pass this through the anonymous function. Here's the code I'm trying.

```
  element.addEventListener("click", function(this){selectActiveCompetitor(this)});
```

sekectActiveCompetitor is reliant on this being passed to it so it can target the right div

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Are you targetting the clicked div?

Comment: See, the thing is - when you attach an event listener like this with `element.addEventListener` (instead of element.onclick = ) the function has automatic access to the `this` keyword, since the function is now 'a part of' the element. Therefore, `this` refers to the object with the attached event - you don't need to pass it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment above, here's an example of the automatic access to the `this` keyword I spoke of. Clicking any of the buttons will cause the text on that particular button to be alerted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function allByTag(tagName,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tagName);}

function forEachNode(nodeList, func){for (var i=0, n=nodeList.length; i<n; i++) func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList); }

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    forEachNode( allByTag('button'), function(curNode, curIndex, nodeList){ curNode.addEventListener('click', onBtnClick, false); } );
}
/*
// expanded version of the above function
//
function onDocLoaded()
{
    var btns = allByTag('button');
    forEachNode(btns, attachBtnHandler);

    function attachBtnHandler(curNode, curIndex, nodeList)
    { 
        curNode.addEventListener('click', onBtnClick, false); 
    } 
}
*/


function onBtnClick(evt)
{
    alert(this.textContent);
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>This is btn1</button>
    <button>This is btn2</button>
    <button>This is btn3</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing, why doesn't it add the onClick to the html? If I inspect element it doesn't have the onclick event listener, where as the manually created divs I'm modeling this after do.

Comment: Because it's a 'javascript event', it doesn't appear in the DOM. If you select the event listeners tab of the element inspector, you can see that they've got handlers for the click event. It's just the way it works. The big advantage (or at least, another one) is that you can add multiple handlers for any one event on the same element. If you instead use `element.onclick = ` this will replace any existing handlers. Each way has benefits, but `element.addEventListener` is by _far_ the more powerful. You can also remove handlers with `element.removeEventListener`. Does this help?